# Which Anaconda version corresponds to which Mac version?

Tags: python, macos, version, anaconda

On [this page](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html) some older Anaconda versions are listed. How can you know which one corresponds to which version of Mac?

Comment: No need to worry. There's just one generic installer for mac. Take the one for the latest version.

Comment: This is not true as of 2022 for mac osx 10.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/#old-os

For macOS 10.5 and macOS 10.6, use the command line installers for Anaconda versions 1.8 and earlier. NOTE: These installer files end in .sh, not .pkg. Download from our archive.

For macOS 10.7 and macOS 10.8, use the command line installers for Anaconda versions 4.2 and earlier. Download from our archive.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no info about which version of Anaconda is made for which OS X, you can still guess it by the OS X release dates:

- OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard - August 28, 2009
- OS X 10.7 Lion - July 20, 2011
- OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion - July 25, 2012
- OS X 10.9 Mavericks - October 22, 2013
- OS X 10.10 Yosemite - October 16, 2014
- OS X 10.11 El Capitan - September 30, 2015
- OS X 10.12 Sierra - September 20, 2016

Compare these dates with the Last Modified column of the page [you linked](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html), or ask the [Anaconda support](https://www.continuum.io/support) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have just installed Anaconda3-4.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg from 
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html on os x 10.7.5
Functions correctly. It has Spyder2  that runs by default Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

you can also use https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/ to upgrade most old macs to get easier compatibility, i wasn't able to install v3 on my mac mini 2011 12.7. so i went with v2 2019.10